# Most efficient algorithm for this problem

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, computer-science

Problem: Let's say I have an array of size N, in range [1, N].
I want to generate a random number k such that 1 <= k <= N, and occupy
arr[k] with a random letter. I will get another random number p, that is different from k,
randomly and occupy that slot. I'll repeat this over and over until there are no slots left. Also, there might be a chance where one of these randomly generated letters might be removed from a slot they previously occupied.

The problem here is that every time I pick a new number, it'll be harder for me to guess a random number that wasn't occupied yet.

I'm trying to find a solution for this problem, obviously in the most efficient way possible (both space and complexity).

I've come up with several solutions but I don't think they're too efficient and I'm having a hard time calculating their complexity.

Plan A) For each integer I randomly choose in the range [1, N], I check if it's occupied. If it is, I re-roll until I get one that isn't occupied. This becomes inefficient with high orders of N as the collisions are pretty high.

Plan B) For each iteration I go over all values of the array, those who I don't occupy I write down in a list. Afterwards I shuffle the list (via Fisher-Yates shuffle for example?) and get arbitrarily the first object. This isn't space efficient, and for my problem, I can't just keep one list and shuffle from there, since in my program there might be multiple threads calculating this.

Plan C) A slight change of plan A: I randomly choose in the range [1, N], I check if it's occupied. If it is, I +1 and try the next one, if it is, again +1. Worst case all array slots are occupied except one -> O(N).

Is there a better way to approach this problem? This specific problem is a very important module in my software so time complexity is vital. If there isn't, which way do you think I should go with (For those who have talent on calculating time complexity). Thank you!

Comment: @JeroenMostert hey, good point! I’ll have to rephrase my question to make this point a bit more clear. In the actual problem there might be a situation where one of these letters are not needed and thus a new slot is unoccupied. I’ll apply this to the post

Comment: A classical method: define an array a[i]=i. Generate k between 1 and N. Select a[k]. Set a[k]=a[N]. Generate a number between 1 and N-1. Select a[k]. Set a[k]=a[N-1] etc.

Comment: Why not making an address list. shuffle it only once, then make all threads top from that list? You already have the "char" arrays. this would just double your memory requirements. Memory is usually cheap. "Edit*: realized it's your second option"

Comment: @xvan Read what I wrote to JeroenMostert, he wrote the same thing

Comment: @Damien fix for my response*** Thanks for the response, but it in a way this removes the idea of randomly placing a letter in an array. I roll a random integer and then move it to the back is just like saying choose k=N. So this doesn’t work... thanks for trying!

Comment: What I proposed is just a simple way to generate a random permutation, i.e. the k, p ... values. It is not clear for me what you want to get at the end, with random positions *and* random letters

Comment: @Damien sorry for not making my problem clear, but hopefully it makes more sense now.

Comment: Maybe useful to mention: the array `a[]` that I used to generate the positions is not the array `arr[]` that you use for the letters

Comment: +1 to @xvan. To my opinion just "doubling" the memory consumption seems totally acceptable in this case (as you already need an array of letters of the same size apparently) and sharing the shuffled numbers list to multiple threads does not seem to be a big deal. And its O(1). Not sure though this solution was meant in "Plan B)".

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you use both plans A and B.

Use A until the array is mostly filled.  Then search for the unused indices, put them into an array, and use plan B.  You will have to experiment with your constraints to figure out when to switch.

Your comment about multiple threads doing this is concerning though.  Be aware that when multiple threads access the same memory, race conditions are easy and contention for access slows you down.